# How to watch assets and automatically install and dump assets with assetic in Symfony

Tags: symfony, less, twig, assetic

I put all my assets in my Bundles
e.g. myBundle/Resources/public/css/

and load them in like so:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
{% stylesheets
'@myBundle/Resources/public/vendor/bootstrap.css'
filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

So everytime I make an adjustment to my css or js, I need to do a `assets:install` and then an `assetic:dump` afterwards to see it in the frontend.

Is there any way to watch the assets in the bundle itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `symlink` option to `assets:install` command. This will make symlink in `web` folder to your bundle `public` folders

```
app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Without `symlink` option this task makes copy of files, so your changes doesn't affect.

You might also want to check `watch` option to `assetic:dump` command

```
app/console assetic:dump --watch
```

Comment: Omg. You just saved me a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: Note that since symfony version 3, the console command is located in the `bin` directory, hence `php bin/console ...`.